# ADT doesn't warn me about calling functions from the wrong API level

Tags: android, adt, android-lint

I have an Android project with minSDK 8 and targetSDK 17. I used a call to a function introduced in API Level 9 (`Camera.getNumberOfCameras()`). ADT doesn't seem to mind this and compiles just fine with no warnings. I set the targetSDK to 8 as well, and it still just builds it fine with no warnings. I would really like it to warn me if my code isn't going to run on an SDK I claim to support. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Also, I gather that if I do want to call a function like this, it's not simply sufficient to enclose it in an if statement that checks the Build.VERSION of the device?

Answer (score 2):

Just change the severity of NewApi in Android Lint Preferences to error.

> Properties --> Android Lint Preferences --> NewApi --> Error in Severity box

Make sure you click the refresh icon in the Lint Warnings windows after every rebuild.

Comment: It's already set as Error. Other Lint warnings seem to be working fine; Eclipse is set to build automatically and other problems are picked up basically straight away. But even if I set the target and min API level to 1 and use functions from API 14 or 17, Lint doesn't report a single error.

Comment: In the Lint Warnings window click the refresh icon. You can show Lint Warnings window by Window --> Show View --> Other --> Android --> Lint Warnings.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is a known bug which will be fixed in the next ADT release.

See: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56427